# Does Angular Bootstrap-ui have any built-in functions to handle opening or closing things?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I don't see any functions on the [bootstrap-ui documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for how I would open or close an element with a function call in a controller.

But let's say on the click of a bootstrapped element, I want to do something special, and then open or close another dropdown:

**template.html**

```
<div dropdown ng-click="customAction()">
  <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>(down arrow)</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.customAction() = function() {
  //doSomething
  var otherDropdown = angular.element(/* select other dropdown */);
  otherDropdown.open(); //How do I do this?
}
```

**Note:** I have purposely abstracted the question because what I am actually trying to do is a bit more complicated than just selecting between two dropdowns. The point is, is there a way to open a dropdown via code, other than just doing `dropDown.addClass('open')`? I ask because I noticed that doing it this way, you also have to keep track of whether `dropdown-menu`'s `aria-expanded` property is true or false; thus, it seems reasonable that there would be a built-in function for handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the dropdown example on the Angular directives for Bootstrap page. There is a sample of a button that toggles the open state of a dropdown.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

The essential mechanism is that you bind the dropdown is-open attribute to a property on your scope/view model, and then you have an event occur that toggles the value of that property.

Comment: Sorry, which button are you talking about? I see the div which is binding its `is-open` property to `status.isopen`, but I do not see anything there modifying `status.isopen`.

Comment: The text of the button is "Toggle button dropdown"

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying to do it that way, but for some reason it isn't working in my code. I'll need to investigate further whether something else is going on in my code.